# deleteing a specific segment from multiple lines

Tags: shell, terminal

the text in my file consists of multiple rows that looks like below:

```
AC_peg_0001__lcl_|CP000251.1_prot_ABC79779.1_1_[locus_tag=Adeh_0001]_[db_xref=InterPro:IPR001957,InterPro:IPR003593,InterPro:IPR013159,InterPro:IPR013317]_[protein=chromosomal_replication_initiator_protein_DnaA]_[protein_id=ABC79779.1]_[location=22..1395]_[gbkey=CDS] DnaA_N  Bac_DnaA    Bac_DnaA_C  
AC_peg_0002__lcl_|CP000251.1_prot_ABC79780.1_2_[locus_tag=Adeh_0002]_[db_xref=InterPro:IPR001001]_[protein=DNA_polymerase_III,_beta_subunit]_[protein_id=ABC79780.1]_[location=1811..2938]_[gbkey=CDS]  DNA_pol3_beta   DNA_pol3_beta_2 DNA_pol3_beta_3 
AC_peg_0003__lcl_|CP000251.1_prot_ABC79781.1_3_[locus_tag=Adeh_0003]_[db_xref=InterPro:IPR001238,InterPro:IPR003395]_[protein=DNA_replication_and_repair_protein_RecF]_[protein_id=ABC79781.1]_[location=2958..4076]_[gbkey=CDS]    SMC_N
```

i want to filter out the parts of lines so that it should look like this:

```
AC_peg_0001__lcl_[locus_tag=Adeh_0001]  DnaA_N  Bac_DnaA    Bac_DnaA_C   
AC_peg_0002__lcl_[locus_tag=Adeh_0002]  DNA_pol3_beta   DNA_pol3_beta_2 DNA_pol3_beta_3 
AC_peg_0003__lcl_[locus_tag=Adeh_0003]  SMC_N
```

Code is:

```
sed -i 's/\|.*\[//g' File_name.txt
```

Comment: Post text, not pictures of text. And read up on POSIX Basic Regular Expression syntax (And the GNU extensions to same if you're using GNU sed; look in the sed manual).

Comment: Good that you have shown your efforts Shradha, please post samples(like what Shawn said above) in form of text of sample of input and expected output in CODE TAGS(like how you wrapped up your `sed` command), so that question looks clearer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this will work:

```
sed -i 's/|/|</g' file_name.txt
sed -i 's/\_\[locus/\_>\[locus/g' 51_Myxo_PFAM_parsed-arranged-final.txt
sed -i 's/<.*>//g' 51_Myxo_PFAM_parsed-arranged-final.txt
```